# No implicits arguments of type T, Trying to cast a dataframe to a Dataset[T]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

I'm trying to build a generic function to consolidate some mongoDb collections, I'm using case classes to type the collections and on my function I receive the type as a parameter `[T]` like this:

```
  def refreshCollection[T](newDS:Dataset[T],oldDS:Dataset[T]): Dataset[T]={
    val filteredOldDS=oldDS.join(newDS, Seq("id"),"left_anti").as[T]
    filteredOldDS.union(newDS)
  }
```

The problem is when I try to convert the Dataframe result of the join to the original case class using `.as[T]` to return a `Dataset[T]` I've got this error even tough I've imported the `sparkSession.implicits._`:

```
no implicit arguments of type: Encoder[T]
```

The interesting part is, when I make the conversion with a fixed case class works fine, any advice on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's because your code doesn't guarantee that there will be `Encoder[T]` available when necessary.

You can try to parametrise your with implicit decoder and postpone the moment when compiler will try to find the required decoder.

```
  def refreshCollection[T](newDS:Dataset[T],oldDS:Dataset[T])(implicit enc: Encoder[T]): Dataset[T]={
    val filteredOldDS=oldDS.join(newDS, Seq("id"),"left_anti").as[T]
    filteredOldDS.union(newDS)
  }
```

Of course, you will need to bring into scope somehow the `Encoder[MyCaseClass]` when calling `refreshCollection`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I think you made a typo in Decoder with Encoder, any way I tried this approach but now I get `No implicits found for  parameter enc: Encoder[MyCaseClass]`

Comment: Yes, right. Corrected. You wrote that when you are doing the conversion for specific case class, then it works. Are you using `import sparkSession.implicits._` then? If so, you need to do the same import when calling `refreshCollection()`

Comment: if writing a method with specific type worked fine but it doesn't work when you make it generic and when you're calling it, it would mean that maybe there is another import that brings the encoder into scope than `import sparkSession.implicits._`, which you have in the place where you define `refreshCollection`, but you didn't add it to place where you call the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was calling the function from another class so yes, I had tom import `sparkSession.implicits._` as well, thanks again!